# Удаление записей из связных таблиц SQL

Tags: sql, libre-office

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу запрос в LibreOffice Base, но появляется ошибка (Состояние SQL: 37000
Код ошибки: -11)

```
 DELETE Klienti, Zakazi
 FROM Klienti
 LEFT JOIN Zakazi ON Zakazi.Kod_klienta=Klienti.Kod_klienta
 WHERE Klienti.Familiya="Петров";
```

Comment: `DELETE 
 FROM Klienti
 LEFT JOIN Zakazi ON Zakazi.Kod_klienta=Klienti.Kod_klienta
 WHERE Klienti.Familiya="Петров";` попробуйте

Comment: @lDrakonl Ошибка: Table not found in statement [DELETE FROM Klienti]

Comment: `Klienti` это таблица?

Comment: `DELETE Klienti, Zakazi
 FROM Klienti
 WHERE Klienti.Familiya="Петров";` а если вот так?

Comment: @lDrakonl да)))

Comment: @lDrakonl Unexpected token KLIENTI, requires FROM in statement [DELETE Klienti]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я поступил бы следующим образом:

`delete from zakazi where kod_klienta in (select kod_klienta from klienti where familiya = 'Петров')`
`delete from klienti where familiya = 'Петров'`

собственно сама конструкция `delete with Inner Join` в sql
`DELETE T2
FROM Table2 as T2 INNER JOIN Table1 as T1
ON T1.Id = T1.Id;`

Answer (score 0):

Я не работал в Libre Office, но есть опыт в других СУБД, могу конечно ошибаться... Но я думаю оно не работает из-за того что, вы пытаетесь удалить 2 таблицы, используя связывание этих таблиц. Если вам просто нужно удалить таблицы то напишите:

```
DROP TABLE Klienti;
```

А если же вы хотите удалить поля в таблице то вам нужно будет поменять немного ваш запрос:

```
DELETE FROM Klienti WHERE Klienti.Familiya="Петров";
```

И на эту таблицу поставить триггер на удаление записей в ней, чтобы после удаления в таблице "Klienti" удалялось поле в таблице "Zakazi"